# How to intergrate retrieval using ConversationalRetrievalChain from langchain library to my chatbot?

Tags: python-3.x, langchain

I’m building a chatbot and I would like to equip it with the ConversationalRetrievalChain. On https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/chat_vector_db there is a use case with ConversationalRetrievalChain. The problem is that I cannot integrate it with my vectorstore database. For the purpose of building vectors, I’ve used llama_index (the result of the xreating index consist of 4. files:

graph_store.json

vector_store.json

index_store.json

docstore.json

So far my code look like this (it wroks but, it doesn’t have retrieval):

```
import os
import openai
import gradio as gr
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from llama_index import StorageContext, load_index_from_storage
from langchain import OpenAI
from translate import Translator
from langdetect import detect

openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=200)

def create_query_engine():
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="store_final")
    index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
    return query_engine

query_engine = create_query_engine()

has_replied = False

def detect_and_translate(final_response):
    # Truncate the final_response to a maximum of 500 characters
    truncated_response = final_response[:500]
    
    # Detect the language of the truncated_response
    detected_language = detect(truncated_response)
    
    # If the detected language is English, return the truncated_response as it is
    if detected_language == 'en':
        return truncated_response
    
    # If the detected language is different from English, translate the truncated_response to English
    translator = Translator(from_lang="en", to_lang=detected_language)
    translated_response = translator.translate(truncated_response)
    
    return translated_response

def click_response(message, history):

    if not message.strip():  # Check if the input message is empty or contains only whitespace
        return " "
    
    greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey", "greetings", "good day", "good morning", "good evening", "good afternoon", "hola", "hallo", "bonjour", "ciao", "witaj", "hej", "howdy", "cześć", "hejo"]

    if any(greeting in message.lower() for greeting in greetings) and len(message.split()) <= 2:
        return "Hi! Thank you for contacting Company. I am a Company bot created to answer your product questions. How can I help you today?"
    
    # Combine previous conversation into context
    conversation_context = "\n".join([f"User: {user_msg}\nBot: {ai_msg}" for user_msg, ai_msg in history])
    
    # Replace "you" and "yours" with "Company"
    message = message.replace(" you ", " Company ")
    message = message.replace(" your ", " Company's ")
    message = message.replace(" yours ", " Company's ")
    
    global has_replied
    response = ""
    if not has_replied:
        response = "Hi! Thank you for contacting Company. I am a Company bot created to answer your product questions. "
        has_replied = True
    else:
        response = response

    memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=15)
    for user_msg, ai_msg in history:
        memory.chat_memory.add_user_message(user_msg)
        memory.chat_memory.add_ai_message(ai_msg)

    conversation = ConversationChain(
        llm=llm,
        verbose=True,
        memory=memory
    )
    # Query the storage_context to get a relevant response based on the message.
    storage_response = str(query_engine.query(message))
        
    # Check if the response from the storage context is valid or empty.
    # Here we assume that a valid response should be at least 20 characters long. Adjust as needed.
    if len(storage_response) > 20:
        intermediate_response = storage_response
    else:
        intermediate_response = ("Hi! Thank you for contacting Company. I am a Company bot created to answer your product questions. I’m sorry, I don’t know the answer to your question. Please send an email to "
                                 "support@Company.com with your query and our team will get back to you as soon as "
                                 "possible. Thank you for your patience and understanding. "
                                 " ")
    
    intermediate_response = intermediate_response.replace("mciszewska@Company.com", "support@Company.com")
    
    # Detect the language of the translated_response
    detected_language = detect(intermediate_response)
    
    # Translate and return the final_response
    translated_response = detect_and_translate(intermediate_response)

    # If the detected language is different from English, translate the closing statement
    if detected_language != 'en':
        closing_statement = " Please let me know do you have any further questions at this moment?"
        translated_closing_statement = Translator(from_lang="en", to_lang=detected_language).translate(closing_statement)
        final_response = translated_response + translated_closing_statement
    else:
        closing_statement = " Please let me know do you have any further questions at this moment?"
        final_response = intermediate_response + closing_statement

    return final_response

demo = gr.ChatInterface(
    click_response,
    title="Company Bot",
    theme="JohnSmith9982/small_and_pretty",
    retry_btn=None,
    description="Hi! I am a Company bot created to answer your product questions. How can I help you today?",
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch()
```

I was trying for the last few days integrate ConversationalRetrievalChain in it, but I've run out ideas how to do it :( Do you have a clue how could I update my code to make it work with ConversationalRetrievalChain?

the code I used for creating index is as follows:

```
def create_index(path):
max_input = 4096
num_output = 4096
tokens = 200
chunk_size = 500

# define prompt
promptHelper = PromptHelper(max_input, num_output, chunk_overlap_ratio=0.1, chunk_size_limit=1024)

# define LLM 
llmPredictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=tokens))

# load data
csv_docs = SimpleDirectoryReader("/path1").load_data()
pdf_docs = SimpleDirectoryReader("path2").load_data()
docs = csv_docs + pdf_docs

# create vector index
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llmPredictor, prompt_helper=promptHelper)

vectorIndex = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents=docs, service_context=service_context)
vectorIndex.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="store_final")

create_index('store_final')
```

Comment: could you please share index creation code so that I can check it locally

Comment: Hi, do you maybe have any thoughts or ideas? I would be very grateful for any input

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine for your code

Replace this code with below code

```
 conversation = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory
)
```

New code

```
 chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, 
         vectorstore.as_retriever(), #this your database(index) retriever
         memory=memory,
         verbose=True
         )
```

Comment: I've tried to use such code (actually I had such attempts before raising this question), but I get the following error: "NameError: name 'vectorstore' is not defined". Each time I try to define vectorstore either by indicating specific folder, file or using loaders, I get other errors as well. I have no clue how I could successfully link line "vectorstore.as_retriever()" with my actual vectorestore database

Answer (score 0):

define vectorstore as so:

```
from torch import cuda
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, OnlinePDFLoader
from langchain.document_loaders import Docx2txtLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import pinecone,time,os    
PINECONE_API_KEY = os.environ.get('PINECONE_API_KEY', 'your key')
    PINECONE_API_ENV = os.environ.get('PINECONE_API_ENV', 'asia-southeast1-gcp-free')
    # initialize pinecone
    pinecone.init(api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY,  # find at app.pinecone.io
            environment=PINECONE_API_ENV  # next to api key in console
    )
    embed_model_id = 'sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
    # use GPU if available
    device = f'cuda:{cuda.current_device()}' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
        
embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
        model_name=embed_model_id,
        model_kwargs={'device': device},
       encode_kwargs={'device': device, 'batch_size': 32})
#to figure out the dimension for your vector index due to embedding model chosen
docs = [
    "this is one document",
    "and another document"
]

embeddings = embed_model.embed_documents(docs)

print(f"We have {len(embeddings)} doc embeddings, each with "
      f"a dimensionality of {len(embeddings[0])}.")

file="https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.08885.pdf"
#file="../data/Study session 8 solution.docx"
try:
    loader = PyPDFLoader(file)
    data = loader.load()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred with PyPDFLoader: {e}. Trying with UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader.")
    try:
        loader = Docx2txtLoader(file)
        data = loader.load()
    except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred with UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader: {e}")
data[0]
text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500, chunk_overlap=0)
docs=text_splitter.split_documents(data)
index_name="651024b1e6577d145be0a85f"
index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
index.describe_index_stats()
vectorstore = Pinecone.from_documents(docs, embed_model, index_name=index_name)
index.describe_index_stats()
```